# Speeding Up Loop

Tags: r, loops

I've read that it's slower to "build out" a data frame with a loop than to initialize one of large size, fill in, and then pare down. I'd like to know if there's a much more efficient way to do this via either initializing a data frame, or maybe using an apply type functionality.

I have a vector of 500 stock symbols for which I want to return 3 columns of information: "trade date," "ticker," and "exerniv30d." I'd like to do this over a date range (startDate to endDate). Within the loop I simply row bind and go to the next date.

The code is fairly slow (it is eventually a tibble of ~151,767 rows), and I'm not sure if it's because of the way I'm calling for the data, or because of the structure of the looping (I was getting size errors when trying to get data for all 500 symbols at once, so I had to split up the 500 symbols into 2 separate requests).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(zoo)
library(Quandl)

# Getting vector of tickers --------------------------------------------------------
    url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"

    SP500 <- url %>%
      xml2::read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
      html_table()

    SP500 <- SP500[[1]]

 #cleaning vector to remove/replace troublesome values
    SP500 <- SP500 %>% arrange(Symbol) %>%
      filter(Symbol != "CBOE")    

    SP500 <- SP500$Symbol
    SP500 <- replace(SP500,match("BF.B",SP500),"BF_B")
    SP500 <- replace(SP500,match("BRK.B",SP500),"BRK_B")

    tickers <- c(SP500,"SPY")

# Initializing variables for loop-------------------------------------------------
startDate = as.Date("2020-01-02")
endDate = as.Date("2021-03-16")
cols_to_fetch <- c("tradedate","ticker","exerniv30d")

holderframe <- tibble()

while(startDate < endDate) {
  
  d1<-Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', ticker = tickers[1:300], tradedate=startDate, qopts.columns=cols_to_fetch,
                       paginate = TRUE)
  d2<-Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', ticker = tickers[301:length(tickers)], tradedate=startDate, qopts.columns=cols_to_fetch,
                       paginate = TRUE)
  d <- bind_rows(d2,d1)
  
  holderframe <- bind_rows(holderframe,d)
  
  startDate <- startDate + 1
  
}
```

Comment: Your code is returning empty data frames for me (d1 and d2). How does it work on your machine?

Comment: it's possible/probable you need a Quandl API Key, which is a major omission in the way I asked my question. The code works great for me, like I said, just kinda slow. Totally usable, just want to learn/optimize.

Comment: I made an API key but am still getting empty data frames. I'll try to debug, but if I were you I'd see my answer below. It should work

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd parallelize this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(zoo)
library(Quandl)
library(rvest)
library(furrr)

# Getting vector of tickers --------------------------------------------------------
    url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"

    SP500 <- url %>%
      xml2::read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
      html_table()

    SP500 <- SP500[[1]]

 #cleaning vector to remove/replace troublesome values
    SP500 <- SP500 %>% arrange(Symbol) %>%
      filter(Symbol != "CBOE")    

    SP500 <- SP500$Symbol
    SP500 <- replace(SP500,match("BF.B",SP500),"BF_B")
    SP500 <- replace(SP500,match("BRK.B",SP500),"BRK_B")

    tickers <- c(SP500,"SPY")

# Initializing variables for loop-------------------------------------------------
startDate = as.Date("2020-01-02")
endDate = as.Date("2021-03-16")
start_dates <- seq(startDate, endDate, by = 'day')

cols_to_fetch <- c("tradedate","ticker","exerniv30d")

N_CORES <- number_of_cores_you_want_to_use
plan(multisession, workers = N_CORES)

get_data <- function(startDate) {
  d1 <- Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', ticker = tickers[1:300], tradedate=startDate, qopts.columns=cols_to_fetch,
                       paginate = TRUE)
  
  d2 <- Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', ticker = tickers[301:length(tickers)], tradedate=startDate, qopts.columns=cols_to_fetch,
                       paginate = TRUE)

  bind_rows(d1, d2)
}

## map over the function in parallel
df <- start_dates %>%
  future_map_dfr(
    get_data
  )
```

Comment: Trying this and the errors I'm getting are on the Quandl side. "You have exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50 calls per day. To make more calls today, please register for a free Quandl account and then include your API key with your requests." Even though I have initialized an API key. Might the multisessions be needing API keys for each? I'll spend some time reading about furrr as well

Another error I experienced is "message": "You have exceeded the API speed limit. Please slow down your requests by reducing the number of requests made at the same time." } }

Comment: You can also try using `purrr::map` instead of `furrr::future_map` to run the requests sequentially, which will probably get you around the rate limit. The other thing worth trying is adding a `Sys.sleep(5)` or so to the function to wait a couple seconds between function calls